# Ratio of Gamma Functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, gamma-function

Is it possible to show that:
\begin{align}
\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{78}\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{29}{78}\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{35}{78}\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{53}{78}\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{55}{78}\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{61}{78}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{78}\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{28}{78}\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{32}{78}\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{44}{78}\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{58}{78}\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{70}{78}\right) } = \sqrt{3}
\end{align}

There are other known ratios of Gamma functions, but as always there seems to be a product rule or trick to evaluate the ratios.

Comment: Well yes, else you wouldn't have that particular identity to post. Not to be condescending, but posting a reference, your own work, and motivation would be appreciated.

Comment: $$\frac{\Gamma(1/34)\Gamma(9/34)\Gamma(13/34)
\Gamma(15/34)\Gamma(19/34)\Gamma(21/34)
\Gamma(25/34)\Gamma(33/34)}{\Gamma(3/34)\Gamma(5/34)
\Gamma(7/34)\Gamma(11/34)\Gamma(23/34)
\Gamma(27/34)\Gamma(29/34)\Gamma(31/34)}
= 1 .
$$ See Amer. Math. Monthly, November 2010, page 842

Answer (score 5):

This has been sitting around quite a while. This seems to rely on
$$\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(z\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(z+\frac13\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(z+\frac23\right)=2\pi\frac{\sqrt3}{3^{3z}}\operatorname{\Gamma}(3z)$$
So the ratio is
$$\begin{align}r&=\frac{\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac1{78}\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{29}{78}\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{35}{78}\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{53}{78}\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{55}{78}\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{61}{78}\right)}{\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac2{78}\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{28}{78}\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{32}{78}\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{44}{78}\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{58}{78}\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{70}{78}\right)}\\
&=\frac{\color{red}{\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac1{78}\right)}\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{29}{78}\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{35}{78}\right)\color{red}{\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{53}{78}\right)}\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{55}{78}\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{61}{78}\right)\color{red}{\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{27}{78}\right)}}{\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac2{78}\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{28}{78}\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{32}{78}\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{44}{78}\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{58}{78}\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{70}{78}\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{27}{78}\right)}\\
&=\frac{2\pi\sqrt3\color{red}{\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{29}{78}\right)}\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{35}{78}\right)\color{red}{\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{55}{78}\right)}\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{61}{78}\right)\color{red}{\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{3}{78}\right)}}{3^{3/78}\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac2{78}\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{28}{78}\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{32}{78}\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{44}{78}\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{58}{78}\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{70}{78}\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{27}{78}\right)}\\
&=\frac{12\pi^2\color{red}{\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{35}{78}\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{61}{78}\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac9{78}\right)}}{3^{12/78}\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac2{78}\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{28}{78}\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{32}{78}\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{44}{78}\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{58}{78}\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{70}{78}\right)\color{red}{\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{27}{78}\right)}}\\
&=\frac{24\pi^3\sqrt3}{3^{39/78}\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac2{78}\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{28}{78}\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{32}{78}\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{44}{78}\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{58}{78}\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{70}{78}\right)}\\
&=\frac{24\pi^3\sqrt3\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{54}{78}\right)}{3^{39/78}\color{red}{\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac2{78}\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{28}{78}\right)}\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{32}{78}\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{44}{78}\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{58}{78}\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{70}{78}\right)\color{red}{\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{54}{78}\right)}}\\
&=\frac{12\pi^2\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{54}{78}\right)}{3^{33/78}\color{red}{\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{32}{78}\right)}\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{44}{78}\right)\color{red}{\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{58}{78}\right)}\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{70}{78}\right)\color{red}{\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{6}{78}\right)}}\\
&=\frac{2\pi\sqrt3\color{red}{\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{54}{78}\right)}}{3^{15/78}\color{red}{\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{44}{78}\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{70}{78}\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{18}{78}\right)}}\\
&=3^{39/78}=\sqrt3\end{align}$$
Beautiful to see those dominos fall like that!

Answer (score 3):

One method to find such formulas is the duplication formula
$$
\Gamma(z) \Gamma(z+1/2) = 2^{1-2z} \sqrt{\pi} \Gamma(2z),
$$
and apply it to nominator and denominator, e.g., to obtain
$$
{\Gamma(1/8) \Gamma(5/8) \Gamma(6/8) \over \Gamma(2/8) \Gamma(3/8) \Gamma(7/8)} = \sqrt{2}.
$$
There seem to be more advanced ideas in Deligne, P. Valeurs de fonctions L et périodes d'intégrales, Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, R.I., 1979.